# Laravel: Custom login path doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel

I set my login path to be 123. Here's how I did it:

In `routes/web.php`, I posted this:

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('123', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('123', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

I deleted the default `Auth::routes();` line in the same file.

Like it should, `localhost:8000/login` generates this error:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

But, when I type `localhost:8000/123`, I get:

```
ReflectionException in RouteSignatureParameters.php line 39:
Method App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index() does not exist
```

after getting redirected to `localhost:8000/home`.

So there is some sort of weird redirect going on here. /home doesn't exist, so probably that is the direct reason for the error. But why does it redirect at all? It should go to the login page!

Help please.

Comment: try to put /123 like this Route::get('/123', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login'); does that make a difference?

Comment: You can simply do this in `AuthController` change your default path:
`protected $loginPath = '/123'` This will redirect to `123` when user is not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have cached routes to me.

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan route:cache`

Should remove any cached routes created by the `Auth::routes();` function.

The redirect takes place because of a setting in `Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController`

```
 protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: Thank you. Does your last point about the redirect mean that I should remove this line in LoginController?

Comment: For the record, `php artisan route:cache` generates   `[LogicException]                                                     
  Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure. `

Comment: Presumably you do want a redirect after login, so I would create a `/home` route for now which will prevent the last error you get.

Comment: Going on the fact that the redirect is being triggered, it also looks like you are actually logged in as well.

Comment: I restarted the server many times to I don't understand how I'm still logged in